# What is mean by types.Info?

Tags: docker

I'm using go template to extract the information from "docker info" command in the json format.

I'm using following command:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker info --format '{{json .CpuCfsPeriod}}'
```

I'm getting following error:

```
template: :1:7: executing "" at <.CpuCfsPeriod>: can't evaluate field CpuCfsPeriod in type types.Info
```

What could be the reason of this erro?
I'm  able to extract other information using same kind of command,
e.g.

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker info --format '{{json .Debug}}'
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an unexpected behavior.

[The struct](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/api/types/types.go#L161) is tagged as shown below:

```
type Info struct {
  ID                 string
  CPUCfsPeriod       bool `json:"CpuCfsPeriod"`
}
```

And the field name it's properly displayed when you list the json properties using `--format '{{json .}}`.

But the only way you can access that property is using the struct field name.

```
docker info --format '{{json .CPUCfsPeriod}}'
```